Does meromorphy in each variable imply joint meromorphy?
Let $f:\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ be a complex valued function which is meromorphic in each of the two variables separately. Is it meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$?
It is not clear to me if this is true or not because the definition of meromorphy states that $f$ must be locally a quotient of two holomorphic functions but meromorphy in each variable only shows that locally in each variable this holds.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

There is Sakai theorem about this, but it has conditions on the domain of the function. It has to be defined except on a set $E$, which is closed, nowhere dense, and for any neighborhood $U$ of any point in $E$ the set difference $U-E$ is connected. Then meromorphy in each variable implies joint meromorphy. There was a similar question about rational functions on MathOverflow.

Oh nice, didn't know about the Sakai theorem. Thanks, a lot.
